# Extract particular fields from json array Nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have the following input json, which has an array of json:

```json
{
  "ArrayList": [
    {
      "a": "value1",
      "b": "value2",
      "c": "value3"
    },
    {
      "a": "value4",
      "b": "value5",
      "c": "value6"
    },
    {
      "a": "value7",
      "b": "value8",
      "c": "value9"
    }
  ]
}
```

And the desired output is :

```json
{
  "ArrayList": [
    {
      "a": "value1",
      "b": "value2"
    },
    {
      "a": "value4",
      "b": "value5"
    },
    {
      "a": "value7",
      "b": "value8"
    }
  ]
}
```

What will be the Jolt transform spec expression for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you want to remove the attribute **c** of objects of the **ArrayList** array, then a **remove** transformation might be used such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "ArrayList": {
        "*": {
          "c": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```